Expressions Algorithm in TypeScript
I have some list of expressions,
const expressions = [
    'A&(B|C)',
    'A|(B&C)',
    'A|(B&(C|D))',
    'A|(B&C&D)',
];

Out of this, I need to get an output like,
[[A, B], [A, C]]
[[A], [B, C]]
[A, [B, C], [B, D]]
[A, [B, C, D]] 

I tried to do this in the below way, But getting an empty arrays instead of correct result.
class ParsedExpression {
    operator: string | null;
    variables: string[];
    subExpressions: ParsedExpression[];

    constructor(operator: string | null, variables: string[], subExpressions: ParsedExpression[]) {
        this.operator = operator;
        this.variables = variables;
        this.subExpressions = subExpressions;
    }
}

function parseExpression(expression: string): ParsedExpression {
    const stack: ParsedExpression[] = [];
    let currentExpr: ParsedExpression | null = null;
    let currentVariable = '';

    for (const char of expression) {
        if (char === '(') {
            if (currentExpr !== null) {
                stack.push(currentExpr);
            }
            currentExpr = null;
        } else if (char === ')') {
            if (stack.length > 0) {
                const prevExpr = stack.pop();
                if (prevExpr !== null && currentExpr !== null) {
                    prevExpr.subExpressions.push(currentExpr);
                    currentExpr = prevExpr;
                }
            }
        } else if (char === '&' || char === '|') {
            if (currentExpr === null) {
                currentExpr = new ParsedExpression(char, [], []);
            } else {
                currentExpr.operator = char;
            }
        } else {
            if (currentExpr === null) {
                currentExpr = new ParsedExpression(null, [], []);
            }
            currentExpr.variables.push(char);
        }
    }

    return currentExpr as ParsedExpression;
}

function generateCombinations(parsedExpr: ParsedExpression): string[][] {
    if (!parsedExpr.operator) {
        return [parsedExpr.variables];
    }

    const leftCombinations = parsedExpr.subExpressions.length > 0 ? generateCombinations(parsedExpr.subExpressions[0]) : [[]];
    const rightCombinations = parsedExpr.subExpressions.length > 1 ? generateCombinations(parsedExpr.subExpressions[1]) : [[]];

    const combinations: string[][] = [];
    for (const left of leftCombinations) {
        for (const right of rightCombinations) {
            combinations.push(left.concat(right));
        }
    }

    return combinations;
}

const expressions = [
    'A&(B|C)',
    'A|(B&C)',
    'A|(B&(C|D))',
    'A|(B&C&D)',
];

for (const expr of expressions) {
    const parsedExpression = parseExpression(expr);
    const combinations = generateCombinations(parsedExpression);
    console.log(`Expression: ${expr}`);
    console.log(`Combinations: ${JSON.stringify(combinations)}`);
    console.log('-------------------');
}

Output I get,
Expression: A&(B|C)
Combinations: [[]]
-------------------
Expression: A|(B&C)
Combinations: [[]]
-------------------
Expression: A|(B&(C|D))
Combinations: [[]]
-------------------
Expression: A|(B&C&D)
Combinations: [[]]
-------------------

Anyway to resolve this?

Which LLM wrote generateCombinations?

I used chat gpt

You confused it by using the word "combinations".  What it's attempting to do is completely unlike what you want.

It obviously didn't understand that variables and subExpressions might both be non-empty. But that is also something to think about: this structure does not retain in which order the operands were presented when this mix occurs.

any way to resolve this issue?

You could try asking chatgpt the right question.  What you're trying to do is convert a Boolean expression into disjunctive normal form.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form

Oh. This is great. I will try to understand this. If I have any questions, I will post. Thank you so much

still no luck on this

The generateCombinations function does not do anything that relates to the task. It should actually flatten the tree to two levels, where the top level is a disjuction, and the second level consists of conjunctions.
You can do this with recursion, and flatten on the way out of recursion.
I have chosen an implementation where the parser allows parentheses to be optional, in which case & gets precedence over |, and the variable names can consist of more than one character. The parser builds a binary tree. I wouldn't store variables in a separate array, but allow a child to be a variable (string) or a node.
In a second phase the tree can be converted to an array of arrays, bottom-up, where this nested array will represent either a CNF (conjunction normal form) or DNF (disjunction normal form). This representation will need to convert from one to the other to allow a node's children to be merged. This conversion is nothing else than a Cartesian product.
Finally some simplifications could be applied, so that the bottom level arrays only have unique values (so to change A&A&B to A&B). More simplification rules could be added (as can be seen in the additional test case I added), but I didn't pursue this further.
Below is a JavaScript implementation. It should not be difficult to add typing:


class BinaryNode {
    constructor(value, left, right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

function parseToBinaryTree(expression) {
    const precedence = { "&": 2, "|": 1, "(": -1, ")": 0, "": 0 };
    const operators = [];
    const operands = [];
    for (const token of expression.match(/[^&|()\s]+|\S?/gs)) {
        if (token in precedence) {
            if (token !== "(") {
                while (precedence[operators.at(-1)] >= precedence[token]) {
                    if (operands.length < 2) throw new Error("Parser: Syntax error: operands length < 2"); 
                    operands.push(new BinaryNode(operators.pop(), ...operands.splice(-2)));
                }
            }
            if (token && token !== ")") operators.push(token);
            else operators.pop(); // "("
        } else {
            operands.push(token);
        }
    }
    if (operands.length != 1) throw new Error("Parser: Syntax error: left over");
    return operands.pop();
}

const unique = values => [...new Set(values)];
const uniqueEach = arrays => arrays.map(unique);
const unwrapSingle = values => values.length === 1 ? values[0] : values;
const unwrapSingleEach = arrays => arrays.map(unwrapSingle);

function product(arrays) {
    if (arrays.length === 0) {
        return [[]];
    }
    const result = [];
    for (const x of arrays[0]) {
        for (const rest of product(arrays.slice(1))) {
            result.push([x, ...rest]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function normalize(root, operator="|") {
    if (typeof root === "string") { // Leaf node
        return [[root]];
    }
    const terms = uniqueEach([
        ...normalize(root.left, root.value),
        ...normalize(root.right, root.value)
    ]);
    if (root.value !== operator) {
        return uniqueEach(product(terms));
    }
    return terms;
}

const expressions = [
    'A&(B|C)',
    'A|(B&C)',
    'A|(B&(C|D))',
    'A|(B&C&D)',
    'A&(B|C)&(C|D)',
];

for (const expr of expressions) {
    const root = parseToBinaryTree(expr);
    const disj = unwrapSingleEach(normalize(root));
    console.log(`Expression: ${expr}`);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(disj));
    console.log('-------------------');
}




Great answer with explanation. this works perfect. I will go through this and will ask questions if I have any. Thank you so much

Why do we have "": 0  in const precedence = { "&": 2, "|": 1, "(": -1, ")": 0, "": 0 };

It's there because the regular expression returns the empty string as the final match (by \S?). This is useful to flush the stacks with the while loop in one last iteration of the tokens loop. This empty string acts much like a closing parenthesis, but then for the top level of the expression (that didn't start with an opening parenthesis).

Great. thanks. Do we need if (operands.length < 2) {             console.log("operands length < 2");             return;           } this? we can remove it right?

Something like that is only necessary if there is a chance that the input string is not valid, like when it would start with &.

Yes. thought the same. Thank you so much again.
